# CSS reponsive background image

Tags: html, css

I am building a website with a container and a background image but is de client is a mobile device want to prevent the client from loading this image.
For bigger screens would I like to use +-5 images with a different resolution for every device width. But I don't find a way to use this
`<img style="width: 100%;" src="./img/normal.png" srcset=" img/lowres.png 700w, img/normal.jpg 900w, img/highres.jpg 1100w" alt="test img">`

in CSS, now I am using an regular high res image. (But it shouldn't load on mobile and be an appropriate size for every desktop)

````
max-width: 2560px;
background-image: url("../img/test_image_2.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You could conditionally load different background images using CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Browsers only load in actively used background images, so you could implement this like so:

```css
background-image: url("../high_resolution.jpg");

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  /* on devices/windows smaller than 600px this attribute
   * will override the previous `background-image` property
   */
  background-image: url("../low_resolution.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)**, you can use the ***`<picture>`*** tag

```
<picture>
   <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg"/>
   <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg"/>
   <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva"/>
</picture>
```

Alternatively, you can use ***media queries*** in your css stylesheet, in this way:

```
.element_class{background-image: url('elva-800w.jpg');}

@media only screen and (max-width: 799px) {
    .element_class {
        background-image: url('elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg');
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .element_class {
        background-image: url('elva-800w.jpg');
    }
}
```